# AWS Athena column cannot be resolved

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a query which should return a row number column that starts from 1 regardless of the conditions from the `WHERE` statement. The problem is that when I try to access it I am receiving the following error:

> Column 'page_rn' cannot be resolved

This is my query:

```
SELECT t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER () as page_rn
FROM (SELECT row_number() over() AS rn, t.*
      FROM transactions t
     ) t
WHERE page_rn BETWEEN 0 AND 10 AND
      date > CAST('2021-03-01' AS DATE)
```

How can I make the query work with the `page_rn` included in the `WHERE` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you want to do this :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT row_number() over() AS rn,t.*
        FROM transactions t
        where date > CAST('2021-03-01' AS DATE)
    ) t
WHERE rn BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```